# powershell - skip section of script or jump to another section

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script with 4 stages.

1. run VM in azure,
2. install software on it,
3. change regkey and
4. verify things.

Sometimes script fails at stage 2 or 3 and when I re-run it it perform stage 1 again.
I want to add functionality where I can pass parameter in command so script would directly run from specific stage. eg skip stage 1 and start running from 2 to end at 4.

How could I can achieve this goal? I mean what features of powershell I should use?

Thank you,
Nilay

Comment: Closest thing to a batch files `goto` function...is a function. Separate them into functions and call on them separately with different parameters if needed. Much simpler than using loops with control of workflow.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it’s a good fit for functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.1).

Then you can pass a parameter and make a `switch` statement for this parameter.

Like:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet("test", "install")]
    [string] $mode
)
#write functions here to be used later


switch ($mode) {
    "test" {
        #run test functions here 
    }
    "install" {
        #run install functions here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but this only call one function. my need is to run script from that point to bottom.

Comment: You can write many functions, it doesn’t have to be one. I presented the one-of-many script workflow idea.